# How to fill in a three dimensional array using for nested loop

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop

I want to create a three-dim array using nested loop, the problem is that the loop doesn't seem to work. 
the code is:

```
s = array(NA,dim=c(5,5,4),dimnames=list(0:4,0:4,1:4))
for (i in 1:4)
{
  for (j in 0:i )
  {
    for (k in 0:i)
    {
      s[j,k,i]=(j+i+k)
    }
  }
}
```

I hope every element in the matrix(e.g. element(j,k,i) could be (j+k+i), however, there are many NAs in the final result, how can I change my code to make it work?

Comment: (1) when you index with `[j,k,i]`, you are indexing on the numeric columns, not the names you assign. If you want to use the names, they must be character, such as `s[as.character(j),as.character(k),as.character(i)]` (which will solve the `"0"` plane being missed. (2) The rest of the `NA`s are because of your loops. Are you expecting zero?

Comment: (Said differently, `s[1,1,1]` is grabbing the first cell in the first position in each axis, whereas `s["1","1","1"]` is grabbing the second row, second column, first z-plane, based on your dim-names.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as this array will form three matrixs, I hope for the first matrix, the element in row 1 and col 2 is 0+1+1( j=0,k=1,i=1), but the loop I wrote created a NA.

Comment: I think you missed my point. The element in row `1`, column `2`, plane `1` is not the same as the element in row `"1"`, column `"2"`, plane `"1"`. When you use strings instead of numbers, it works fine for me. (`s[1,2,1] == 2` is true for me.)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some other languages, in R, there is no zero element in original base structures. So attempting to assign a 0th element does not assign (and interestingly does not raise a warning or error). So as @r2evans comments, you need to reference by assigned `dimnames` which are always coerced to character values.

Additionally, to fill all NAs, for all possible combinations, the inner `for` loops need to extend to full length of values and not terminate at `i`

```
### BY DIMNAMES
s1 <- array(NA, dim=c(5,5,4), dimnames=list(0:4,0:4,1:4))

for (i in 1:4)
{
  for (j in 0:4)     # DO NOT END AT i
  {
    for (k in 0:4)   # DO NOT END AT i
    {
      s1[as.character(j),as.character(k),as.character(i)] <- (j+i+k)
    }
  }
}
```

However, you *can* reference by appropriate index adding a `1` to each inner loop and of course adjusting the additions to align with first. In fact, this tends to be faster than above for more iterations per timings below.

```
### BY INDEX
s2 <- array(NA, dim=c(5,5,4), dimnames=list(0:4,0:4,1:4))
for (i in 1:4)
{
  for (j in 1:5)
  {
    for (k in 1:5)
    {
      s2[j,k,i] <- as.integer((j-1) + (i-1) + k)
    }
  }
}

identical(s1, s2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Alternatively, consider an *apply* solution with `mapply` for loop-hiding by first producing all possible combinations with `expand.grid()` and then iterate through vectors element-wise. And instead of assigning by index and worrying about `dimnames`, you assign across all elements with `[]`:

```
s3 <- array(NA, dim=c(5,5,4), dimnames=list(0:4,0:4,1:4))

prms <- expand.grid(j=0:4, k=0:4, i=1:4)
s3[] <- mapply(function(i,j,k) (j+i+k), prms$j, prms$k, prms$i)

identical(s1, s3)
#[1] TRUE
```

At [small iterations](https://rextester.com/NAGOA41744), `mapply` is slightly longer than `for` versions. But at [larger iterations](https://rextester.com/UVQRX58719), it is comparable or slightly faster than the indexing approach.

---

Of course, if you can always aim for vectorization which your example can do with simple arithmetic of `+` by adding all combination vectors without `for` or *apply* looping. This would be the fastest approach. See above demo links:

```
s4 <- array(NA, dim=c(5,5,4), dimnames=list(0:4,0:4,1:4))

prms <- expand.grid(j=0:4, k=0:4, i=1:4)
s4[] <- prms$j + prms$k + prms$i

identical(s1, s4)
#[1] TRUE
```